# compile error lyx var/folder does not exist

Tags: lyx

When I compile the `lyx` document to get the PDF I receive an error message

> /var/folder..... does not exist

that is the start of the temp directory root but for other files I didn't received this error message.

Help required.

Comment: What is your OS? I've never had this problem on Ubuntu. What do you have under Tools > Preferences > Paths under "Temporary directory"?

Comment: I have OS X Yosemite. In temporary directory I have by default /var/folders/l4/bdk79k191g9dg5n71n57cdkr0000gn/T @scottkosty

Comment: Try changing that to '/tmp'. There is '/tmp' folder on OS X right?

Comment: Thanks does works. In temporary directory when you use a Mac you have to write \private\tmp @scottkosty

Comment: OK glad it works. If you experience the same issue on a fresh install, can you please make a bug report at http://www.lyx.org/trac. This would help fix problems for future users.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Tools > Preferences > Paths.

Under "Temporary directory", put "\private\tmp".